# In the example below the function object "rev" is defined in terms of itself. How is this possible?

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, functor

This example (`void function f(string& s1, string& s2)`) was taken from page 297/298 of B.Stroustup's new book "TCPL" 4th edition.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

void f(std::string& s1, std::string& s2)
{
    std::function<void(char* b, char* e)> rev =
                [&](char* b, char* e) { if (1<e-b) { std::swap(*b,*--e); rev(++b,e); } };
    rev(&s1[0],&s1[0]+s1.size());
    rev(&s2[0],&s2[0]+s2.size());
}

int main()
{
    std::string s1("Hello");
    std::string s2("World");
    f(s1, s2);
    std::cout << s1 << " " << s2 << '\n';
}
```

The code compiles and prints out the correct results, i.e., function `f` reverses the characters of the input strings. Program output:

> olleH
>   dlroW

I can understand the semantics of the expression below. My problem is to accept its syntax, as the variable `rev` is defined in terms of itself.

```
std::function<void(char* b, char* e)> rev =
                    [&](char* b, char* e) { if (1<e-b) { std::swap(*b,*--e); rev(++b,e); }
```

Comment: It's recursive, and you seem to know it. What is the question?

Comment: In fact, it's not defined in terms of itself; it's initialised with an object containing a reference to itself. It's possible because the language allows you to take a reference to an object wherever its in scope.

Comment: Note the subtlety: the `point of declaration` of `rev` is, syntactically, exactly at the occurrence of the declarator `rev`.  After that (including the equals sign and everything that follows), `rev` now represents a valid object with a known type (and size), and it can be used like any other defined variable in scope.

Comment: Also - for what it's worth - think about how the compiler builds this code.  When it compiles the *call* to `rev` (inside the function definition), this is simply building a stack frame and calling a `jmp` - the actual *function* being called is irrelevant, as long as its signature and location is known (and the latter information is available to the compiler at the point of *declaration*).  The rest of the function is, of course, straightforward for the compiler to build as well.  So despite the seeming strangeness of 'defining a function in terms of itself', it works straightforwardly.

Comment: @DanNissenbaum Great answer. I'm ready to accept it as such. Tks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(From comments beneath question)

Note the subtlety: the **point of declaration** of `rev` is, syntactically, exactly at the occurrence of the *declarator* `rev`:

```
                                   // vvv Point of declaration
std::function<void(char* b, char* e)> rev =
    [&](char* b, char* e) { if (1<e-b) { std::swap(*b,*--e); rev(++b,e); }
```

After that (including the equals sign and everything that follows), `rev` now represents a valid object with a known type (and size), and it can be used like any other defined variable in scope.

Also, think about *how the compiler builds this code*:

When it compiles the call to `rev` (inside the function definition), this is:

- simply **building a stack frame** (with known parameters being passed), and
- **calling a jmp** (to a known address)

... The actual function being called is irrelevant, as long as its signature and location is known (and the latter information is available to the compiler at the point of declaration).

The rest of the function is, of course, straightforward for the compiler to build, as well.

So, despite the seeming strangeness of 'defining a function in terms of itself', it works straightforwardly.

Comment: (+1) Again, thanks for the great and insightful answer.

Answer (score 7):

The lambda captures everything by reference with `[&]`. This also includes `rev` and allows for this syntax.